# Proving a statement in Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Hi I'm currently studying Linear algebra and I just want to get a few bits straight in my head about it:

- If I had a vector space - $V$ and $S = \{u_1, u_2\}$ is a subset of $V$ . How can I prove that $S$ is linearly independent?

I just don't understand how I can prove this?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_independence

Answer (score 0):

A proof by contradiction is an approach you can use. Assuming that $u_1\neq \alpha u_2$ where $\alpha \in F$and none of them are the zero vector the list is then linearly independent. For suppose it is not then $\exists a_1, a_2\in F$where both do not equal zero, or one does not equal zeros such that $a_1u_1+a_2u_2=0 \Rightarrow u_1=\frac{-a_2}{a_1} u_2$. Where $a_1 \neq 0$ or else that implies that $u_2$ is the zero vector. But this means that $u_1$ is a scalar multiple which we stated was untrue. Thus by contradiction it follows that the list is linearly independent.

Comment: Assuming V is a vector space over a field F.